# calculate midpoint

Tags: floating-point, bisection

Why in the bisection method it is better to compute the midpoint c between a and b with

```
c = a + (b - a) / 2.
```

instead of the simpler:

```
c = (a + b) / 2.
```

all variables are floating points.

Comment: Are we talking `int` or `float` ? And can you include a reference to "why it is better" ?

Comment: Why do you believe the first method is better?  It involves one extra floating-point operation compared to the second method;  it risks overflow in the rare case where `a` and `b` are huge with opposite signs (whereas the second method risks overflow in the almost equally rare case where `a` and `b` are huge with the same sign); ignoring overflow, the second method will always compute a correctly-rounded midpoint on a typical machine.  So does the first, at least when `a` and `b` are close (and possibly in general;  I'm not sure).  So I don't see any clean win for the first method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it is to avoid any potential overflows / loss of precision in intermediate calculations.

Comment: Overflow shouldn't be a problem with floating point types. Loss of precision might be.

Comment: mmm, I've studied that the subtraction operation is worse than addition with near floating points numbers, so why I loose precision with + and not with -?

Comment: How and why? I can't seem to find an explanation for why this works.